# Add sign-in and Create Account link in custom header

Tags: magento2, header, link

I have created a custom header.phtml file to make my custom header.
See https://prnt.sc/r7dtnu
Now I want to add Sign in and Create an Account link in this.
How can I add here?

Comment: You want the <a href> for both links, right?

Comment: yes.. how it works for default. The same way

Answer (score 1):

You can simple add using anchor tag in your header phtml file.

```
<a href="/customer/account/login">Sign In</a>
<a href="/customer/account/create">Create an Account</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to add the links to your custom header.phtml file

```
<a href="<?= $block->getUrl('customer/account/login'); ?>"><?= __('Sign in') ?></a>
<a href="<?= $block->getUrl('customer/account/create'); ?>"><?= __('Create an Account') ?></a>
```